# Python 2.6.5 - <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>

Tags: python, ssl

Trying to read a website using Python 2.6.5 but getting the ssl error ''.

I am using urllib2. I have seen solutions for 2.7 but not for 2.6.5. I can't upgrade the version to 2.7. Please can someone suggest a solution for this one?

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, req_args, timeout=timeout)
```

File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1169, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/local/test/python/exec/2.65/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: 
Caught URLError. - 2017-01-23 13:07:36

Comment: It's impossible to say from this description what the error is: there are many reasons why you could get this error. At least you should add the URL you are trying to access and the openssl version used by python.

Comment: url: https://www.dosm.gov.my/v1/index.php?r=column/ctwoByCat&parent_id=80&menu_id=YmJrMEFKT0p0WUIxbDl1bzZydW9JQT09

Comment: Trying to open url 'https://www.dosm.gov.my/v1/index.php?r=column/ctwoByCat&parent_id=80&menu_id=YmJrMEFKT0p0WUIxbDl1bzZydW9JQT09' using urllib2 on Python 2.6.5.

Comment: proxy_sup = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)
cookie_jar = cookie_jar or cookielib.CookieJar()
cookie_proc = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_sup, cookie_proc)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
hdrs = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', "pragma": "no-cache"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdrs, unverifiable=False)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req, req_args, timeout=timeout)

Comment: To cite myself: *"At least you should add ... and the openssl version used by python."*. I don't see any mention of this version. If it is still 0.9.8 then the problem is not the old python but the old OpenSSL which does not support any ciphers required by the server. To find out `python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'`

Comment: OK thanks a lot. Looks like OpenSSL is older version. I am using ssl version that comes with Python 2.6.5. Have not installed separately.

The version I have does not have the attribute 'OPENSSL_VERSION'.

python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPENSSL_VERSION'